# I want to show a 0% data without a column in stackbar chart in android using highchart

Tags: android, highcharts

Hi I am plotting the stack chart using Hicharts library in android. According to our requirement i have to show the columns in the graph based on the percentage of the data, but if my percentage is 0 also i need to show the label as 0% but there should not be any column for that data. For example if you see below graph I have total 3 columns in the graph which are high, low and In-target. If I have data from all the types then graph will look like below.
[image]

Lets say if I have only "High" data and I dont have data from "low" and "In-target" i.e, 100% High and 0% low and In-target, then I have to show the graph like below. How can I acheive this using highcharts. Please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am able to acheive this by Giving the verticle alignement "top" for high, "middle" for In-Target and "bottom" for Low.